# primefaces p:photocam was blocked by chrome

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I use the p:photocam component of primefaces 6.2, but it stopped working in the last few chrome

the browser displays the following error

[Deprecation] URL.createObjectURL with media streams is deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use HTMLMediaElement.srcObject instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5618491470118912 for more details.

/javax.faces.resource/photocam/photocam.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.2

Is there any way to reuse component?

Camera image doesn't appear to be captured.

Comment: File an issue with PrimeFaces that photocam needs to be updated

Comment: Please post the answer you posted in the webcamjs forum...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem was because p:photocam was inside a p:dialog.
When I removed from inside the p:dialog it started to work.